# How to toggle between boolean based on another value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean, components, toggle

***If a user is selected from the list, the boolean is true, when the selected user is unselected from the list, the boolean is false. The boolean will remain true if another user is selected from the list.
Here's my code:***

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Users from "./Users";

export default function UserApp() {
  const [ selectUser, setSelectUser ] = useState(null);
  const [ isUserSelected, setIsUserSelected ] = useState(false);
  const handleUserClick = (user) => {
    setSelectUser((prev) => (
      user !== prev ? user : null
    ))
    if(selectUser === null) {
      setIsUserSelected(!isUserSelected)
    } else {
      setIsUserSelected(isUserSelected)
    }
  }

  console.log(selectUser);
  console.log(isUserSelected);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Users selectedUser={handleUserClick} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i can only see a single Users component, we will probably need the code for that as well

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski, I just added the other component

Answer (score 0):

Update your if statement:

```
if(selectUser !== null) {
      setIsUserSelected(true)
    } else {
      setIsUserSelected(false)
    }
```

OR:

```
if(selectUser === null) {
      setIsUserSelected(false)
    } else {
      setIsUserSelected(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether user is selected or not without using hooks. All you need is one state hook.

```js
const User = props => {
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState(null);
  
  const handleUserSelect = user => setSelectedUser(user.id === selectedUser.id ? null : user);

  return (
    <>
       <Users onSelectUser={handleUserSelect} />
       <Checkbox checked={Boolean(selectedUser)} />
    </>
  )

}
```

If `selectedUser` is `null` `Boolean(selectedUser)` will return false otherwise it will return true. You don't need extra hook for this.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to store the 'isUserSelect' information since it will be redundant with the 'selectUser === null' condition.

Here is a code proposal

```
export default function UserApp() {
  const [ selectedUser, setSelectedUser ] = useState(null);
  
  const handleUserClick = (user) => {
    if(selectedUser === user) {
      setSelectedUser(null)
    } else {
      setSelectedUser(user)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Users onUserClick={handleUserClick} />
    </div>
  )
}


export default function Users({ onUserClick }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {USERS_DATA.map((user, index) => (
        <li
          key={index}
          className="users"
          onClick={() => onUserClick(user)}
        >
          {user.user_name}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

note: code not tested, might contain some typos